# Is it possible to exploit PHP's unserialize by using only builtin classes?

Tags: php, class, serialization, built-in, exploit

I'm using PHP 7.3. Is it possible to **[exploit PHP unserialization](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection)** with **[PHP builtin classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)** only?

It seems that builtin classes have natively some [`magic functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) implemented (most probably for serialization / unserialization). It can be verified with this code:

```
<?php

$classes = get_declared_classes();
sort($classes);

// __autoload is deprecated
$magic_methods = ["__construct", "__destruct", "__call",
  "__callStatic", "__get", "__set", "__isset", "__unset",
  "__sleep", "__wakeup", "__toString", "__invoke",
  "__set_state", "__clone", "__debugInfo"
];

$classes_test_magic = [];
$classes_test_magic["className"] = $magic_methods;

foreach ($classes as $className) {
    foreach ($magic_methods as $magicMethod) {
        if (method_exists($className, $magicMethod)) {
            $classes_test_magic[$className][] = 1;
        } else {
            $classes_test_magic[$className][] = 0;
        }
    }
}

header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=builtinClassesMagicMethods.csv");
$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($classes_test_magic as $className => $methodsStatus) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_merge([$className], $methodsStatus));
}
fclose($fp);
```

[image: Overview of available magic methods in PHP builtin classes]

Comment: You can add those magic methods to any of your own custom classes. They are kind of events that are triggered at some specific moments in your class life cycle. Those methods are not necessarily for serialization.

Comment: @Musa Please, next time read more carefully my question. I'm not asking about usual unserialization exploitation.